# Can <section> be inside <div>?

Tags: html

I am working on one project and must place the `<section>` inside the `<div>`. And I have searched on google regarding it. But I can't find the solution.

```
<div>
  <section>
    <div>Content</div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Can we place the `<section>` tag inside `<div>`? Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: Yes, it can. Is it right? Depends on project, semantics, design. In general it isnt possible answer you.

Answer (score 3):

Well, just put it into a [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea):

[image: HTML Validation Result]

So the answer is: yes.

Answer (score 1):

It can be inside the `div` element. The `div` has no semantic meaning. It used only for creating a layout structure.